# Python 3 Float Decimal Points/Precision

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

I am reading a text file with floating point numbers, all with either 1 or 2 decimal points. I am using `float()` to convert a line into a float, and raising a `ValueError` if that fails. I am storing all floats in a list. When printing it out, I'd like to print it out as a 2 decimal places floating point.

Assume I have a text file with the numbers `-3.65, 9.17, 1`. I read each one, and once I convert them to float and append them to a list. Now in Python 2, calling `float(-3.65)` returns `-3.65`. In Python 3 however, `float(-3.65)` returns `-3.6499999999999999` which loses its precision.

I want to print the list of floats, `[-3.6499999999999999, 9.1699999999999999, 1.0]` with 2 decimal points only. Doing something along the lines of `'%.1f' % round(n, 1)` would return a string. How can I return a list of all two decimal points of floats, and not strings? So far, I rounded it using `[round(num, 2) for num in list]` but would need to set the decimal points / precision instead of `round()`.

Comment: In python 2, `float(-3.65)` is `-3.6499999999999999` too.. This is *normal*. `float` is by it's very nature not 100 precise.

Comment: Not in mine: `Python 2.7.2 (v2.7.2:8527427914a2, Jun 11 2011, 15:22:34)                                                                     │
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin                                                                         │
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.                                                        │
>>> float(-3.65)                                                                                                              │
-3.65`

Comment: Also, let me point out I know that `float` is not precise and I know the reasoning behind this. I'm looking an answer that will show how to print it out in 2 decimal points in Python 3. Thanks

Comment: Basically, you just can't really do this because of the way float point works. I suggest you consider using the `Decimal` class in the `decimal` module.

Comment: That is just the representation of Python rounding it to at most 16 positions behind the decimal.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In a word, you can't.

`3.65` cannot be represented exactly as a `float`. The number that you're getting is the nearest number to `3.65` that has an exact `float` representation.

The difference between (older?) Python 2 and 3 is purely due to the default formatting.

I am seeing the following both in Python 2.7.3 and 3.3.0:

```
In [1]: 3.65
Out[1]: 3.65

In [2]: '%.20f' % 3.65
Out[2]: '3.64999999999999991118'
```

For an exact decimal datatype, see [`decimal.Decimal`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html).

Comment: So there is no way to limit the number of decimal points as an number type? To print 3.65, I would require to print it out as a string?

Comment: @Darksky One can *only* print strings. Sometimes the conversion isn't as explicit: but it is always done.

Comment: Yes, so how would I represent `3.64999999999999991118` as `3.65` or anything that's 2 decimal points, without it being a string? Any other type than float that I can use?

Comment: Use `Decimal` in the `decimal` module instead of float point.

Comment: I thought Python had this change awhile ago. A change to `float` formatting so that it tried to be the shortest string that would convert back into the exact `float` you were printing. Basically an attempt to make these kinds of rounding issues disappear most of the time. Did that change not make it into Python3? I thought I saw it in the changelog for 2.6 or 2.7.

Comment: @Omnifarious: I've just tested, and I am seeing no difference between 2.7.3 and 3.3.0

Comment: @NPE: I'm researching now. But my preliminary research leads me to believe that I'm remembering something about the `str` method and/or the `%g` format specifier.

Comment: @NPE: Ahh, yes, it's `repr`. And it changed in Python2.7. Python3 also has it, so it's not different. http://docs.python.org/2.7/whatsnew/2.7.html (search for 7117) and http://bugs.python.org/issue7117

Answer (score 86):

The comments state the objective is to *print to 2 decimal places*.

There's a simple answer for Python 3:

```
>>> num=3.65
>>> "The number is {:.2f}".format(num)
'The number is 3.65'
```

or equivalently with f-strings (Python 3.6+):

```
>>> num = 3.65
>>> f"The number is {num:.2f}"
'The number is 3.65'
```

As always, the float value is an approximation:

```
>>> "{}".format(num)
'3.65'
>>> "{:.10f}".format(num)
'3.6500000000'
>>> "{:.20f}".format(num)
'3.64999999999999991118'
```

I think most use cases will want to work with floats and then only *print* to a specific precision.

Those that want the *numbers themselves* to be stored to exactly 2 decimal digits of precision, I suggest use the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) type. [More reading on floating point precision](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) for those that are interested.

Comment: Using f-strings does not seem to be very readable to another user who may not be aware of the feature. On the other hand, the using "{}".format() is much more intuitive when reading.

Answer (score 59):

The simple way to do this is by using the round buit-in.

`round(2.6463636263,2)` would be displayed as `2.65`.

Comment: Though be aware of the note from the [documentation on `round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) that `round()` can give surprising results when given float values.  The example mentioned there: "`round(2.675, 2)` gives `2.67` instead of the expected `2.68`."

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
num = input("Please input your number: ")

num = float("%0.2f" % (num))

print(num)
```

I believe this is a lot simpler. For 1 decimal place use `%0.1f`. For 2 decimal places use `%0.2f` and so on.

Or, if you want to reduce it all to 2 lines:

```
num = float("%0.2f" % (float(input("Please input your number: "))))
print(num)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to understand through this below function using python3

```
def floating_decimals(f_val, dec):
    prc = "{:."+str(dec)+"f}" #first cast decimal as str
    print(prc) #str format output is {:.3f}
    return prc.format(f_val)


print(floating_decimals(50.54187236456456564, 3))
```

**Output is : 50.542**

Hope this helps you!

Comment: The OP didn't need a variable to define precision - it was set at 2 places. But for variable precision, you don't need to use the arcane string addition `prc = "{:."+str(dec)+"f}"`.

Instead, embed the precision: `print("The number is {:.{}f}".format(f_val, dec))`.

The same but with f-strings: `print(f"The number is {f_val:.{dec}f}")`.