# Convert a list of string floats to a list of floats with 2 decimal points

Tags: python, list, floating-point, decimal

Did my research and made several improvements, got very close to solving this issue but now I'm stuck and need help please.

Task: To convert a list of strings floats to floats with 2 decimal points

Original list:

```
mylist = ['17.21', '33.40', '24.39', '3.48', '1.02', '0.61', '18.03', '1.84']
```

Aim

```
mylist = [17.21, 33.40, 24.39, 3.48, 1.02, 0.61, 18.03, 1.84]
```

My script attempts

```
mylisttwo = map(float, mylist)
```

It gave me this

```
[17.21, 33.4, 24.39, 3.48, 1.02, 0.60999999999999999, 18.03, 1.84]
```

Then I thought id format it

```
floatlist = []
for item in mylisttwo:
    floatlist.append("{0:.2f}".format(item))
```

but that gave me a list of string floats again!! arghhhh

```
['17.21', '33.40', '24.39', '3.48', '1.02', '0.61', '18.03', '1.84']
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: If you want them as floats and you are planning to do calculations with them, I wouldn't bother rounding them to 2 decimal places until the time when you need to display them.

Comment: Why do you care?  (Serious question.)  Is `0.60999999999999999` good enough for your purposes?  If not, why not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[round(float(i), 2) for i in mylist]`

This should work. Format is for inserting strings in other strings, as in `"Hello, {}! What is your favourite {}?".format("Jim", "colour")`.

If you want to the numbers to only exist to 2 decimal places, you could use the decimal module.

Comment: The rounding isn't accurate because of the way float is represented in python: 
http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round, but you're answer appears to be more relevant than simply saying 'its impossible', as said here in a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540143/python-3-float-decimal-points-precision

Comment: I see where I went wrong, thanks. But in the software I'm using it gives me this [17.21, 33.4, 24.39, 3.48, 1.02, 0.60999999999999999, 18.03, 1.84]. index 5 wasn't rounded to two decimal points for some reason.

Comment: See the above comment, computers work in binary, so just as in base 10 we can't represent 1/3 as a decimal exactly - it's 0.33333333333... - computers without an infinite amount of memory can't store some floating point numbers accurately.

Comment: What about using the Decimal module?

Comment: `round` is not helpful here:  your `round(float(i), 2)` won't change a thing.  `float("0.61")` *already* returns the closest representable float to `0.61`, and the result of the `round` call will again be the closest representable float to `0.61`.

Comment: I presumed the questioner didn't know how many decimal places they would be to in the list, although I suppose that isn't necessarily true looking at the example list he gave.

Answer (score 1):

You asked a question "What am I doing wrong here?".
I think, what you are doing wrong is passing as an argument to:

```
floatlist.append()
```

this:

```
"{0:.2f}".format(item)
```

Format method of str class is simply returning formatted string, and you are expecting to get fixed two decimal points float. Float does not give such an option. [user2387370](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2387370/user2387370) is right, you should use Decimal.

Answer (score 0):

solution is similar with `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

np.round( [float(i) for i in mylist], 2)
```

returns:

`array([ 17.21,  33.4 ,  24.39,   3.48,   1.02,   0.61,  18.03,   1.84])`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following code that takes your original list and maps it to your "Aim":

```
from decimal import Decimal

def str_to_float_with_precision(item):
    precision = 2
    return float(Decimal(item, precision))

items = ['17.21', '33.40', '24.39', '3.48', '1.02', '0.61', '18.03', '1.84']
floated_items = map(str_to_float_with_precision, items)
print floated_items
```

The result:

```
[17.21, 33.4, 24.39, 3.48, 1.02, 0.61, 18.03, 1.84]
```